# Find partial duplicate lines in a file and count how many time each line was duplicated?

Tags: linux, file, count, grep, duplicates

I want to count how many duplicates are there in my log file.
for example if the following was my log

```
[2018-10-17 15:25:24,243] [ERROR] python - Users: Unable to retrieve 1  
[2018-10-17 15:25:24,272] [ERROR] python - Users: Unable to retrieve 2  
[2018-10-17 15:25:24,280] [ERROR] python - Users: Unable to retrieve 3  
[2018-10-17 15:25:24,281] [ERROR] python - Users: Unable to retrieve 2  
[2018-10-17 15:26:45,759] [ERROR] python - CATP: Unable to retrieve 1  
[2018-10-17 15:26:48,432] [ERROR] python - Users: Unable to retrieve 3  
[2018-10-17 15:26:48,460] [ERROR] python - Users: Unable to retrieve 1
```

i want the output to be

```
Users: Unable to retrieve 1 : 3  
Users: Unable to retrieve 2 : 2  
Users: Unable to retrieve 3 : 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not interpreting it wrong, a single line of AWK would suffice.

`awk '{m[$NF]++} END{for(k in m) print k,"unable to retrieve",m[k]}' test.txt`

Where `test.txt` is your log file.

It's a pretty straightforward one-liner, as it just examines the last field in each line, accumulates them and at last printing.